# How to send encrypted mail with microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I want to send an encrypted mail with microsoft graph api. Sending normal mails works as outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
however this option of outlook web does not seem to be available:

[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/411535/secure-encrypted-mail-api.html) mentioned sending email with [MIME content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mime-message).